# R ordering splitting up ordering of entries with different number of digits to left of decimal

Tags: r, sorting

When I create a simple data frame,

```
dd <- data.frame(x = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'),z = c(11.2, 1.1, 911, 2,34453,11.2,106.45,44,22,12,1,19,19.1))
> dd
   x        z
1  a    11.20
2  b     1.10
3  c   911.00
4  d     2.00
5  e 34453.00
6  f    11.20
7  g   106.45
8  h    44.00
9  i    22.00
10 j    12.00
11 k     1.00
12 l    19.00
13 m    19.10
```

I am able to order the rows by the z column,

```
> dd[order(dd$z),]
   x        z
11 k     1.00
2  b     1.10
4  d     2.00
1  a    11.20
6  f    11.20
10 j    12.00
12 l    19.00
13 m    19.10
9  i    22.00
8  h    44.00
7  g   106.45
3  c   911.00
5  e 34453.00
```

, but when reading from a data frame which is from a 46 X ~5000 .csv file I get a result which seemingly orders the values with two digits to the left of the decimal, then the ones with a single digit to the left of the decimal. How do I order in strictly ascending order?

```
1940                                                       11.8
1976                                                       11.9
1921                                                       12.1
1916                                                       12.4
1967                                                       12.5
1917                                                       12.6
1918                                                       12.6
1975                                                       13.0
1919                                                       13.8
1952                                                       14.3
1930                                                        7.9
1920                                                        8.3
1963                                                        8.4
1950                                                        8.5
1927                                                        8.6
1926                                                        8.7
1960                                                        8.7
1915                                                        8.8
```

Comment: Those are probably factors. Try repeating the read.table step with stringsAsFactors=FALSE and colClasses=c("character","numeric").

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice but I set (using read.csv), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, colClasses=c("Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure" = "numeric"), and received an error "scan() expected "a real" got '"11.4"' "

Comment: You should post a copy of what you see for the first few lines using a text editor (and do so in the body of your question... not in comments. I'm now wondering if you have lots of quotes around numbers.

Comment: Try read.table, stringAsFactors is used with read.table. ?read.table will give you more information.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your column was read in as strings instead of as numbers.

Simply convert to numeric:

```
 dd[["z"]] <- as.numeric(dd[["z"]])
```

If you get a message about `NA`s being coerced in, then you have some sloppy data.

Check which are NA, then check the raw data:

```
 index.to.NAs <- which(is.na(dd[["z"]]))
 rawData <- readLines("path/to.file.csv")
 rawData[index.to.NAs]
```